# Is it true that for all $U$, $W$ non-empty sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ if $U \cup W=\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then $U=\mathbb{R}^n$ or $W=\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I've been thinking about this one for a while, at first I thought it only to be valid if $U,W$ were open (the union of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an open set), then I remembered that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is also a closed set and that the union of closed sets is closed.

I thought about proving this by contradiction, however I am confused in how to proceed.

Comment: It isn't even true if $U$ and $V$ are open sets.  For example, $U = (-\infty,1)$ and $W = (0,\infty)$ are open sets in $\mathbb R$, and $U \cup W = \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, of course not. Consider $n = 1$ and, say, $U = \mathbb{Q}$ and $W = \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Tyrone He didn't say $U$ and $W$ had to be open, but even then, consider $U = (-\infty, 0)$ and $W = (-1, \infty)$.

Comment: So now we have a counterexample where the sets are disjoint, and a counterexample where they are open :)

Comment: Oh yeah you're definitely right on that one, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

The way that it is stated, it is not true (see the answer by Duncan Ramage and the comments)

Judging by the discussion though, this nice question will lead you to the notion of [*connectedness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space). For more info on the topic, any book on topology (or metric spaces) will eventually talk about this notion.

---

Now back to the question, as $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected, it cannot be written as a union of two **non-empty** *disjoint* **open** (or closed) sets.

There are a few ways in which you can prove the connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^n$ but at one point or another, you may want to use the definition of [path connectedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness) (which is much more intuitive) and the implication $\text{ path connected } \implies \text{connected}$. Part of the proof of this implication resembles the proof of compactness of $[0,1]$.

As $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex, it is path connected.

Comment: At least the most obvious proof of (path-connected) implies (connected) uses the fact that the closed interval [0,1] is connected, so the reasoning is a bit circular, at least for n = 1. A more direct proof for this case is needed to make the argument 100% correct and complete.